# Method to find dual basis: solve equations vs kronecker delta

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

When reading FIS, I found the method of finding dual basis is by solving linear system of equations. But since the dual basis has a clear definition by kronecker delta, why can't we just define them this way?

Comment: Both approaches are equivalent.

Comment: But how? Can you give an example?

Comment: I presume the point is: let $\{e_1,e_2\}$ be the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$ and $\{e^1,e^2\}$ be its dual basis. What's the dual basis of $\left\{5e_1-3e_2,\ -e_1-\frac15e_2\right\}$ ?